# Why use an async method and the await to call a GetAsync

Tags: asynchronous

Why use an async method and the await(like the image)to call a GetAsync.The call to the api will still not wait for the response just with the GetAwait using a synchronous method [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWW29.png)

`Like

```
 `Public string Call(string url){...var response = client.GetAsync(url)}...}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why use an async method and the await

The entire point of asynchronous code is to free up the calling thread while the operation is in progress. `async` and `await` allow you to write much more maintainable and natural asynchronous code.

> The call to the api will still not wait for the response just with the GetAwait using a synchronous method

This is true, and this is what `await` provides: a natural way for one method to wait for another to complete. So, the difference between synchronous and `await` is this: synchronous code blocks the calling thread until the response is received; `await` lets the calling thread do other things until the response is received.

To put it another way, `await` pauses the *method*, but not the *thread*.

You may be interested in the [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) I have on my blog.